# how to upload apk file to firebase realtime database by programmatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase real-time database first time, I saw many videos about uploading and retrieving data like images, video and pdf, but I couldn't found any apk uploading video, can anyone provide me documentation or any video link with quite coding change for uploading apk.. thanks in advance

Comment: If you followed the tutorials and are able to upload images, videos and pfd files, then you should be able to upload any file type. What have you done so far? Can you provide us some code?

Comment: @Amit Swami can you please edit the question and add some codes you have tried and also please tell us why do you want to upload apk?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this firebase documentation - [Uploading files on Android - Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)

There's no difference in uploading an image, video or some other file type like APK. Also, please make sure to define proper rules for accessing the Firebase storage to upload your files. Refer [Security rules for firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start)

Answer (score 0):

Its really funny thing ,im predicting fear before doing code of apk file but it is similar to all other methods like to upload pdf and images , by the way thanks to all and for ur couragement